# ERROR: unrecognized configuration parameter "tablespace"

Tags: postgresql, alter, tablespace

I'm trying to move a database in Postgres 8.2 to a new tablespace, but when running  `ALTER DATABASE data_base_name SET TABLESPACE TO tbspc_name`
the following error appears ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "tablespace".

Comment: `ALTER DATABASE ... SET TABLESPACE ...` is not available in [Postgres 8.2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-alterdatabase.html), it was introduced in [Postgres 8.4](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-alterdatabase.html).

Comment: @klin Do you know of any way to move the database to tablespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in Postgres 8.2 you have two options:

- move tables one by one, see [`ALTER TABLE ...`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-altertable.html);
- backup the database, create a new one with a tablespace defined, and restore the backup in the new database, see [`CRETE DATABASE ...`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-createdatabase.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll make the second choice, my database is a bit big.